# How to get both following-sibling::text() and following-sibling::b?

Tags: xpath, text

I'm trying to parse a website to extract people's names and countries.

The page sometimes looks like:

```
<th>Inventors:</th>
    <td align="left" width="90%">
            <b>Harvey; John Christopher</b> (New York, NY)<b>, Cuddihy; James William</b> (New York, NY)
    </td>
```

I can get the country using

```
//th[contains(text(), "Inventors:")]/following-sibling::td/b[contains(text(),";")]/following-sibling::text()

[(New York, NY), (New York, NY)]
```

Sometimes the page looks like ( added around country name):

```
<th>Inventors:</th>
    <td align="left" width="90%">
        <b>Harvey; John Christopher</b> (New York, <b>NY</b>)<b>, Cuddihy; James William</b> (New York, <b>NY</b>)
    </td>
```

I can get the country with:

```
//th[contains(text(), "Inventors:")]/following-sibling::td/b[contains(text(),";")]/following-sibling::b

[NY, NY]
```

Now, I want to be able to get the countries in both cases.

I tried with:

```
//th[contains(text(), "Inventors:")]/following-sibling::td/b[contains(text(),";")]/following-sibling::*[self::text() or self::b]
```

but then I get only the "b"s...

I've also tried:

```
//.../following-sibling::text() | //.../following-sibling::b
```

but I also get only the "b"s...

Any idea why this does not work as expected? Any solution to get both entries?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
string(//th[.="Inventors:")]/following-sibling::td)
```

So that you'll select

```
Harvey; John Christopher (New York, NY), Cuddihy; James William (New York, NY)
```

in both cases.  Then use XPath 2.0 string/regex processing functions, or use those facilities in the calling language if only XPath 1.0 is available.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try something like:

```
//th[contains(text(), "Inventors:")]
    /following-sibling::td/b[contains(text(),";")]
    /following-sibling::node()[not(self::b[contains(text(),";")])]
```

This will select all following-sibling nodes but ignore b nodes containing a ";".